# SQL Identity declarada (1, 1) inserindo 0

Tags: sql-server, null, identity

Estou com um serio problema em meu banco. Algumas de minhas tabelas foram criadas com o Pk e Identity (1, 1) o que é padrão. Porém ao fazer a restauração do banco algumas dessas tabelas ficam com o PK NULL e ao inserir dado na tabela, ele inicia com pk 0; Isso esta gerando mts falhas........ Alguém consegue me ajudar (ja pasaram por isso?)

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
MyTableID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
RecordName nvarchar(100) NULL)

INSERT MyTable(RecordName) 
VALUES('Valor Qualquer')

SELECT * FROM MyTable
-- 0 , Valor Qualquer
```

---

```
Select last_value
From sys.identity_columns
Where object_id = 'MyTable'
```

-- NULL

Como mudar o "NULL" para 0 ?

Comment: Coloque o código de criação da sua tabela na pergunta e também o `INSERT`

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta e adicione os dados nela

Comment: Adicione essas informação no pergunta. Clique em editar e adicione lá. Os comentários não são para mais informações.

Comment: admitindo que _"restauração do banco"_ significa _"instalar um backup"_, encontrei algumas referências confirmando que quando isso acontece algumas _constraints_ (entre outros controles) são perdidas. Dá uma olhada [nesse link](https://www.sqlshack.com/commonly-used-sql-server-constraints-not-null-unique-primary-key/) que explica o que ocorre e como resolver, deve ajudar ;)